# Lua floating point errors in table index

Tags: floating-point, lua

Usually, I compare two floats by seeing if they are within a range of a very small number. It doesn't work for table keys because you do not know if they exist without knowing their key (if that makes sense).

Example with lua 5.1 on a 64 bit computer:

```lua
a, b, c = 1.7, -0.8, -0.4
d = a + b + c -- prevents constant folding
print(string.format('%1.20f', d)) --  0.49999999999999989000  (around 0.5)
assert(d ~= 0.5)
t = {[0] = 'foo', [0.5] = 'bar'}
print(t[d]) -- nil  (I want it to print 'bar')
```

Basically, how can I find a key in a table while accounting for floating point error? I'd want it to work without a comparison to each key in the table, so it can still be fast with big tables. There's probably already a built-in function to do this, but I could not find one.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really must index from floating point numbers coming from different sources, I suggest you convert them to strings in a fixed format of as many decimal places as you want to keep and index the table with those strings.

You can even make this happen automatically by setting an appropriate `__newindex` metamethod for a proxy table.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think about that. Also, nice trick with the __newindex!

Comment: How about multiplying it by a fixed number, and then using `math.floor`.

Comment: @Deco, that works as well but you have to be careful with potential overflow.

Comment: Ah, true... hadn't considered that!
An interesting approach for LuaJIT would be to cast it to a `long long` and then use `ffi.string` (probably with union magic). It'd be very space efficient... but probably isn't worth the effort.
Also, @Ryan: for fixing the number of decimals, you can do `string.format('%.4f', num)`.